# Mock Response.Header (Invalid setup on an extension method: x => x.Append)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, asp.net-core-webapi

In my web api controller class, it returns a json result as well as a response header:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/v1/{ID}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetBookByID(string ID)
{

    var userID = Request.Headers["UserID"]; //Getter from request header
    //...
    Response.Headers.Add("Flag", result.Key ? "Y" : "N"); //Setter for Response Header
    return new ObjectResult(result);
}
```

In my unit test, I am trying to mock the header as follows:

```
 var testHeader = new Mock<IHeaderDictionary>();
 testHeader.SetupGet(x => x["UserID"]).Returns("1001"); 
 testHeader.Setup(x => x.Append("Flag",(StringValues) It.IsAny<string>()));
```

When I stepped through the break point, it breaks in this line:

```
Response.Headers.Add("Flag", result.Key ? "Y" : "N");
```

and I got an error:

> Message: System.NotSupportedException : Invalid setup on an extension
>   method: x => x.Append("Flag", (StringValues)It.IsAny())

Here is what I have tried, but none of them works:

```
testResponseHeader.Setup(x => x.Append("Flag", It.IsAny<StringValues>()));

testResponseHeader.Setup(x => x.Append("Flag", "Y"));

testResponseHeader.Setup(x => x.Append("Flag",(StringValues) "Y"));
```

One thing I was curious is that, it is the response header code that broke the unit tests, not request header code:

```
var userID = Request.Headers["UserID"]; //This didn't break
```

And for the `IHeaderDictionary`, it was to `Represents HttpRequest and HttpResponse headers`. So my question would be why would HttpRequest work in this case, but not HttpResponse?

Comment: You are trying to setup an extension method. Moq can't setup extension methods. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iheaderdictionary?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Clarify what it is you are actually trying to do and what you intend to assert in the test.

Comment: @Nkosi I added some return values in the header and it broke my unit tests. It shows null exception because `Response.Headers` is null. So I was thinking of mocking them so that I am able to make my unit tests passed.

Comment: Show the full test. That way I can get a better  idea of where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I just figured it out. This two lines exists before in my test. It is to mock the `HttpContext.Request` since the controller methods need to get request header values.

```
_mockHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContext>();
_mockHttpContext.Setup(x => x.Request.Headers)
                .Returns(testRequestHeader.Object);
```

After adding this line of code it worked again. Because the controller method needs to return a header response.

```
_mockHttpContext.Setup(x => x.Response.Headers)
                 .Returns(testRequestHeader.Object); //I forgot to add this line!
```